# How to remove password prompt from .Bat file?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, pgagent

I am creating daily backup scheduler for my PostgreSQL database, For that I installed Pg-agent and also created job scheduler. I have created one .bat file and written script in it which is working fine. What I want that when I am executing .bat bat file from command prompt that time it is asking for password so I want to remove that and execute .bat file without asking password.

```
@echo Backup database  %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
@echo off
SET PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_dump.exe"
SET PG_HOST=localhost
SET PG_PORT=5432
SET PG_DATABASE=postgres
SET PG_USER=postgres
SET PG_PASSWORD=postgres
SET PG_PATH=C:\OEM
SET FECHAYHORA=%date:/=%-%time:-0,8%
SET FECHAYHORA=%FECHAYHORA::=-%
SET FECHAYHORA=%FECHAYHORA: =0%
SET PG_FILENAME=zerodefect_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.sql
%PG_BIN% -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% %PG_DATABASE% > %PG_FILENAME%

@echo Backup Taken Complete %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: Tried piping: `echo %PG_PASSWORD%| %PG_BIN% ...`?

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be named `PGPASSWORD` (without the underscore), as stated in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)

On a side note, you may want to add `setlocal` at the beginning of the script and `endlocal` at the end, so the variable containing the password will be removed from memory at the end.